# Double ActionBar/Toolbar

Tags: java, android

I'm having trouble locating the actionbar and why it is showed twice.
There should only be one, with the nav_drawer, App name and the settings button to the right.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the MainActivity I am only setting the layout that have the toolbar and the main_content included.

How it looks like in the preview

[image]

In the emulator

[image]

```
setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer_main);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

//getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
         this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

Comment: You are probably not using the proper parent theme for your `Activity`. What's your theme based on?

Comment: use a `NoActionBar` theme to your style. like `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` or `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`.

Comment: Yes it was the base app theme in the styles.. it was:  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"> Changed it, and it works! Thanks. Damn i used so long time to find the issue, damn.. i was tired too... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifests, use NoActionBar theme for MainActivity

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Add NoActionBar in style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Setup toolbar in MainActivity.java

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your-title-in-String");
```

Comment: It was the base theme in styles, it was DarkActionBar. Changed it and applied setSupportActionBar(toolbar) and everything is good again! ;)